# Rotating a point on a circle

Tags: geometry, rotations

The wheels on a bicycle have $r$-inch radii. After the front wheel picks up a tack, the bike rolls for another $d$ feet and stops. How far above the ground is the tack?

I've been thinking about this problem for a couple of days and I keep coming up against the same issue. I can do the problem fine as long as I have actual numbers for $r$ and $d$, but in the general case I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the angle of rotation. Dividing $d$ by the circumference gives the number of times that the circle rotates, and then to find the angle of rotation I just need multiply the fractional part of this number by 360. In the general case, I keep getting stuck on how to convey the fractional part of a number. I've found that the total number of rotations made is $\dfrac{6d}{r\pi}$; is there a way to notate the fractional part of this number? Is there a way to do this so that I don't need that?

I could write it as $\dfrac{6d}{r\pi}-\lfloor \dfrac{6d}{r\pi}\rfloor$ but I'd like to avoid introducing floor notation if possible.

Comment: 1 rotation = 2$\pi$ radians, so $6d/\pi r$= how many radians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The number of rotations can be found by $\frac{d}{2\pi r}$, or the distance divided by the circumference of the wheel.
- Multiplying by $2\pi$ gets you the total number of radians: $\theta = 2\pi \cdot \frac{d}{2\pi i} = \frac{d}{r}$
- The vertical coordinate of the tack **with respect to the center of the wheel** is generally given by $r \sin \left(\theta \pm \frac{\pi}{2}\right).$ The $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ is a phase shift to describe the fact that the tack is on the ground when it gets picked up. The $\pm$ part depends on whether you consider positive angles to go counterclockwise (i.e. bike traveling to the left) or clockwise (i.e. bike traveling to the right)
- To get the distance from the ground simply add the wheel's radius.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel a bit silly not realizing I should just multiply by $2\pi$.